# Access to listbox in panel by index value c#

Tags: c#, .net, listbox, controls, element

I have a panel which contains 35 listboxes in it. I am making a foreach loop for accessing to these listboxes with these lines;

```
foreach (ListBox empBox in panel4.Controls.OfType<ListBox>())
{
    //do something
}
```

But i want to access to these listboxes by checking their index with for loop.

Like;

```
for (int i = 0; i<panel4.Controls.Count; i++)
{
    Listbox empBox = panel4.Controls[i];
}
```

I know the code i wrote is not correct, but i want to reach to the listbox with index value.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a list (or array) from the listboxes:

```
List<ListBox> listBoxList = panel4.Controls.OfType<ListBox>().ToList();
for (int i = 0; i < listBoxList.Count; i++)
{
    Listbox empBox = listBoxList[i];
}
```

Comment: Thank you Tim, its the thing that i was searching.

Answer (score 0):

You could check whether a control at a specific index in the Controls collection is a ListBox by using the as operator:

```
int index = 1;
ListBox lb = panel1.Controls[4] as ListBox;
if(lb != null)
{
    //there is a ListBox control at index 1
}



for (int i = 0; i < panel1.Controls.Count; i++)
{
    ListBox lb = panel1.Controls[4] as ListBox;
    if(lb != null)
    {
       //there is a ListBox at index i
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need the Index of the ListBox, with respect to **only** the ListBoxes themselves?  If yes, then use Tim's answer.

...or do you need the Index of the ListBox with respect to **all** other controls in the Panel?  If the latter, then do something like:

```
foreach (ListBox empBox in panel4.Controls.OfType<ListBox>())
{
    int index = panel4.Controls.IndexOf(empBox);
    Console.WriteLine(index.ToString() + ": " + empBox.Name);
}
```